# Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer

Being new to raw JavaScript, intervals and times this was not the easiest script to come up with, and thus, although it seems to be working as I want it too the code looks very clunky.

The timer counts down to one of 4 times of day: 8am, 2pm, 8pm or 2am depending on which is the closest. Because they are at six hour intervals there can either be one or a maximum of 2 times that are currently in the future.

Can anyone suggest improvements to the code and how I might be able to make it more dynamic (more than 4 times of day for example)?

```
    <?php
                // define times to count down to and the time now
                $time1  = strtotime(gmdate("08:00:00")).'<br />';
                $time2  = strtotime(gmdate("14:00:00")).'<br />';
                $time3  = strtotime(gmdate("20:00:00")).'<br />';
                $time4  = strtotime(gmdate("02:00:00")).'<br />';
                $timeNow = strtotime('now').'<br />';

                // Get the difference between times
                echo $dif1 = $time1 - $timeNow.' 1<br>';
                echo $dif2 = $time2 - $timeNow.' 2<br>';
                echo $dif3 = $time3 - $timeNow.' 3<br>';
                echo $dif4 = $time4 - $timeNow.' 4<br>';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // 4 reboot times
        var time1 = "<?php echo $time1;?>"; // 8am
        var time2 = "<?php echo $time2;?>"; // 2pm
        var time3 = "<?php echo $time3;?>"; // 8pm
        var time4 = "<?php echo $time4;?>"; // 2am

        // time differences
        var dif1 = parseInt("<?php echo $dif1;?>");
        var dif2 = parseInt("<?php echo $dif2;?>");
        var dif3 = parseInt("<?php echo $dif3;?>");
        var dif4 = parseInt("<?php echo $dif4;?>");

        // count how many times are above zero
        var countDif = 0;

        // Check whether the time differences are above 0 (in the future)
        if(dif1>0){
            countDif = countDif+1;
        }
        if(dif2>0){
            countDif = countDif+1;
        }
        if(dif3>0){
            countDif = countDif+1;

        }
        if(dif4>0){
            countDif = countDif+1;
        }
        // if there is only one time in the future check which 1 it is
        if(countDif == 1){
            if(dif1>0){
                // set countdown to this time difference        
                var secs = dif1;
            }else if(dif2>0){
                // set countdown to this time difference    
                var secs = dif2;
            }else if(dif3>0){
                // set countdown to this time difference        
                var secs = dif3;
            }else if(dif4>0){
                // set countdown to this time difference        
                var secs = dif4;

            }
            // run the timer
            var counter1=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
        // if there are two counters in the future (max of two with 6 hour interval timers) check which two 
        }else if(countDif > 1){
            // check if dif 1 is greater than zero
            if(dif1>0){
                //check if dif2 2 is greater than zero
                if(dif2>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif2
                    if(dif1<dif2){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif1;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif2;
                    }
                }else if(dif3>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif3
                    if(dif1<dif3){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif1;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif3;
                    }

                }else if(dif4>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif4
                    if(dif1<dif4){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif1;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif4;
                    }
                }
            }else if(dif2>0){
                //check if dif2 2 is greater than zero
                if(dif3>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif2
                    if(dif2<dif3){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif2;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif3;
                    }
                }else if(dif4>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif3
                    if(dif2<dif4){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif2;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif4;
                    }

                }
            }else if(dif3>0){
                //check if dif2 2 is greater than zero
                if(dif4>0){
                    // check if dif1 is less than dif2
                    if(dif3<dif4){
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif3;
                    }else{
                        // set countdown to this time difference        
                        var secs = dif4;
                    }
                }
            }   
            // run the timer
            var counter1=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
        }

        var a = 10;
        function timer()
        {

            if(secs == 0){
                //clearInterval(counter1);
                var announce=setInterval(announcement,1000);
            counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
            }else{

                var dh1 = Math.floor(secs/3600) % 24;
                var dm1 = Math.floor(secs/60) % 60;
                var ds1 = secs % 60; 

                secs=secs-1;
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=dh1+"hrs "+dm1+"mins "+ds1+"secs "+"("+secs+")";
            }

        }

function announcement()
    {
        if(a==0){
            clearInterval(announce);
        }else{
            a=a-1;
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="Server is rebooting...";
        }

    }


    </script>



    <span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because they are at six hour intervals there can either be one or a maximum of 2 times that are currently in the future.

True, *BUT* there is still only 1 hour that is closes

This should do the same thing, and you could add more hours to the `hours` array.

What it will do is take the current hour (as of this writing: 16), compare it with the `hours` array and find whats next (in this case: 20), and then we start an interval which will check the time every 1 second.

```
var hours = [ 2, 8, 14, 20 ];
var currentHour = new Date().getHours();
var targetHour = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    if(hours[i] > currentHour) { targetHour = hours[i]; break; }
}

var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
          console.log("running timer...");
          if(new Date().getHours() == targetHour) {
               alert("done");
               //
               /*  Here goes your logic for what should happen when your target hour hits */
               //   
               clearInterval(intervalID); //stop the interval once the hour has been hit  
      }
}, 1000);
```

**edit**

As Simon pointed out we need a way to either break out of the interval once the targeted hour has been hit or we need to make sure that the scope of `if(new Date().getHours() == targetHour)` is not executed every second once the targeted hour has been hit. In this case we invoke `clearInterval` on the interval ID returned by `setInterval`, effectively killing the interval.

Another alternative would be to use a `var targetHourHit = false` variable and only execute the scope of the `if` when our variable is false, and at the end set our variable to true.

Comment: I'd rather not see the same alert message once every second for one hour. But you're on the right track.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I'd rather not see an alert at all, or rarely - but it's a simple way of conveying a message to an user and it's a simple way of distinguishing when a unique or rare conditional has been met.

Comment: This is great @Max thanks I assume I can use the same date class to easily display the current minutes and seconds, the same way you used `gethours`?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Oh, I see your point now... Yeah, you're right.

Comment: @crm - Yes you can! Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for all functions in the Date object.

Comment: My point was that the way I see it, your code here will call some code once every second for an entire hour, while the original.... (sees that there is 1 new comment) yeah, exactly...

Comment: @Max w3schools are also known as [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com), when referencing to JavaScript references it is better to use an official documentation such as [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: So to display an actual count down do I put an `else` for when the current time doesn't match the targethour? and calculate the tiem difference in seconds here?

Comment: How can I account for GMT times using this date object?

Comment: @crm - No, there may be that you don't need an `else` depending on what you want to do. You should give it a try and either update this post or create a new post. Let's see how you would implement it and we'll guide you along the way! :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - <lazy>yupp I know, but it was the first link...</lazy>

Comment: I recommend using `>` instead off `==` in `new Date().getHours() == targetHour` in case the browser pause the timer in background, and you may want the code to trigger even if it's delayed.

Comment: @Vitim.us - If I do that, then it won't trigger on the same hour. I could use `>=`, but it still means it will trigger on the same hour regardless of what minute. If it delays more than an hour there is something else that is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I meant `>=` your computer can always go to sleep or something, and when you wake it up, you should see the notification there.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the things Max wrote, to make sure that you don't make the same mistakes again I wanted to point out several things regarding your current code:

- You're using both PHP and JavaScript. Why I am not exactly sure. You should be able to do everything with JavaScript only.
- You're `time` variables gets set to strings, with an additional HTML `<br />` element. Then you're setting them to JavaScript variables. The JavaScript `time` variables are unused
- Your PHP `dif` variables are set to a string in PHP and then Parsed as an integer in JavaScript. Use only an integer variable and use it as part of an `echo` instead.
- If the time is `01:00:00`, won't all four times be in the future?
- You are using four numbered variables for each thing, the next time you find yourself doing this think: Would using an array help here? Most often the answer is yes.
- Whenever you write messy code like the `if(countDif > 1)` part, you are bound to miss a case, or forget to update one when you make a change, which is very likely to cause bugs. Since you wanted to get the lowest positive value, you could instead use this code:

  ```
  var lowest = 2000000000; // initialize to a very high value
  if ((dif1 > 0) && (dif1 < lowest)) lowest = dif1;
  if ((dif2 > 0) && (dif2 < lowest)) lowest = dif2;
  if ((dif3 > 0) && (dif3 < lowest)) lowest = dif3;
  if ((dif4 > 0) && (dif4 < lowest)) lowest = dif4;
  ```

  However, it is of course a lot better to use an array, as Max has used in his answer.